# How to use Push Notifications Service on windows phone 7.5 , with PhoneGap?

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins, mpns

I am using **PhoneGap** to develop an application on iOS and windows phone 7.5 .

I already succeeded on implementing push notifications on my iOS PhoneGap application , but i am having a hard time to do the same with the windows phone 7.5 one.

Is there a tutorial , to show how i can implement it?

I cant even find the plugin for notifications , like i did on iOS.

Is it even supported??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the PushWosh SDK for PhoneGap.
[Here](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/windows-phone-7-cordova-sdk-integration-guide/) is a short link describing how to implement it.

Comment: Yes that the only one i found too a couple of minutes ago. I am looking at it right now. Do you have any experience with it?